# How many exceptions does one CATCH block catch?

Tags: exception, raku

If multiple exceptions occur in a try{} block and there is only one CATCH{} block inside the try{} block, can this CATCH{} block catch any/all the exceptions? Or do I need one CATCH{} for each possible exception?

```
try { CATCH { default { say "seenError" }; }; die "1"; die "2"; die "3" }
seenError
```

In the example above, which "die" statement was caught? 1st? If I want to handle each exception, do I need to enclose each possible exception within one separate CATCH{} ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: you do **NOT** need a `try` to have a `CATCH` block.  In the Raku Programming Language, a `CATCH` block can live in any lexical scope.

So your example can become:

```
CATCH {
    default {          # $_ contains the exception
        say .message;  # show what the message was
    }
}
die "1";
die "2";
die "3";
say "still alive";
```

If you run it like this, it will just say "1", implying that only the first exception was caught.  And that is correct, because you do **NOT** change anything about the situation: the exception is still active and will cause the termination of your program.

What you need, is to resume execution after the exception was handled.  And there's a method for that: `.resume`.  It doesn't work on all exceptions, but then you will be told it doesn't work.

Changing the program to:

```
CATCH {
    default {
        say .message;
        .resume;  # continue execution after where exception occurred
    }
}
die "1";
die "2";
die "3";
say "still alive";
```

This will show "1", "2", "3", "still alive".

So what does [`try`](https://docs.raku.org/language/exceptions#index-entry-try_blocks) do?  Basically, it adds a `CATCH` block for you that will catch the first exception that it sees, put the exception in `$!` and return with `Nil`.  You could think of a `try` block as a way to turn a fatal exception into a benign failure.  You use it if you're not interested in why something failed.  And `try` can also be a statement prefix.  In short:

```
say try die;  # Nil
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Elizabeth Mattijsen !!! You have furthered my understanding of exception handling and you have saved me 8 hours of work. Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 3):

(Please don't forget to accept Liz's answer. This is just an addendum to her answer.)

As Liz notes:

> you do **NOT** need a `try` to have a `CATCH` block

And, as she implies, neither do you need a `CATCH` block when using `try`:

```
for 1, 2, 3 {
  try { print 'something ... '; .&die } or put "seenError: $!"
}
```

displays:

```
something ... seenError: 1
something ... seenError: 2
something ... seenError: 3
```

As Liz *also* outlines, if an exception is thrown and not `.resume`d during processing of code that's being `try`d, or if there's an unhandled [`Failure`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Failure), the `try` catches the exception/failure, puts the corresponding exception in `$!`, and returns `Nil`.

I mention this to introduce one final option that might be of interest: `trys`, which I created for [my answer to the SOQ **Returning values from exception handlers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695109/1077672).